# why when I start my flash application on a browser it doesn't work well

Tags: database, actionscript-3, browser, adobe-flash-cs3

My application in flash loads/writes informations in a database. It works if I open it in the adobe editor or the executable version. But if I publish it in html and I open it on the browser, I can't connect to the db.
I tried also to change the 'local playback security' in the publishing options, but It does't work.

Comment: That behavior points to either security issues (debug sandbox while testing movie allows all kind of insecure operations) or the fact you used AIR classes that are not supported by Web Flash Plugin. It's difficult to say unless you specify how you read/write your DB.

Comment: There's a way to remove these kinds of security level?